# how to count words correctly in text

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want give my program a text and it count the words correctly
I tried to use an array to save words in it :

```
string[] words = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');
```

But this code has a problem and it is count the spaces in text
so I tried the following code :

```
 string[] checkwords= richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < checkwords.Length; i++)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.Text.EndsWith(" ") )
            {
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                string[] words = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');

                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Words" + " = " + words.Length.ToString();
```

but now it wont work correctly .

Comment: define "correctly". Did you consider Chinese? Hebrew? UTF16?

Comment: show an example of the words that you are trying to count as well.. also have you even stepped through the code..? clean up / format this code in your question too.. also re-read your logic in your `code` you're already splitting the richTextBox1.Text why are you doing it again in string[] words..? very unclear what you're asking I vote to close

Comment: why split the text, run a for loop, then abort the loop if the original string ends with a space? Then what's the point of RE-splitting the text again if there is no space at the end? Check for ends-with-space, THEN split/count

Comment: Don't you want to count spaces more than once? Then use the overload of string.split: `int countWords = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;`

Comment: @sehe I think his code incorporates both Chinese and Latin variations.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is an editor being used. Which version of .Net one is targeting is more important than telling us you use notepad.

Comment: @CalvinSmith Touché. I was, however not talking about the code, but rather about the text it should be able to "correctly" operate on :)

Comment: @sehe I know, I just wanted a little laugh :)

Comment: i use the length of my array to count words . and i dont want my program count the spaces .

Comment: best to brush up on the basics [C# String.Split Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) also why do you refuse to show an example of the text / words that you are working with..? is that too much to ask..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tabh47cf(v=vs.100).aspx) with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to ignore multiple consecutive spaces.

```
string text = "a    b c    d";  // 4 "words"
int words = text.Split(new char[]{}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```

I'm using an empty `char[]` (you can also use `new string[]{}`) because that takes all [white-space characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) into account, so not only `' '` but also tabs or new-line characters.

Comment: thanks Mr Schmelter , its easy and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `Regex` here, using the ['word boundary'](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) anchor

Otherwise your code may not correctly take into account things like Tabs and New Lines - `\b` will take care of that for you

```
var words = Regex
    .Split("hello world", @"\b")
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));

var wordCount = words.Count();
```

Comment: `+1`that's assuming that the `op` can understand `RegEx` the Split()` method is easier for beginners to understand in my opinion but good answer as well

Comment: The problem is tabs, new lines, etc - they won't be picked up by splitting on ' '

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you wish to return if the textbox ends in " ". Maybe it should be a next or continue instead.

If multiple spaces is a possibility.

```
Regex myRege = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}");     

string myText = regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, @" ");

string[] words= myText.Split(" ");

toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Words" + " = " + words.Length.ToString();
```

Just for fun

```
private string[] GetCount(string bodyText)
{
  bodyText = bodyText.Replace("  "," ");

  if(bodyText.Contains("  ")
    GetCount(bodyText)

  return bodyText.Split(' ');
}

string[] words = GetCount(richTextBox1.Text)

toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Words" + " = " + words.Length.ToString();
```

Comment: A problem with this is that the Replace you have would turn three consecutive spaces into two consecutive spaces, i.e. it only replaces occurrences found in a single pass, and does not look again at the location it just replaced.

Comment: I kind of thought it would do it somewhat recursively and examine if after the replace, i could fix that with recursion...